# decompressing tar.gz in rtems operating system

Tags: c, gzip, tar, rtems

I was wondering if there was a specific set of library that can decompress tar.gz files in an rtems operating system. Most of the answer I seen is for linux. I was looking at gzip and libz but was not sure if these were for linux or can I use them for rtems as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some integrated functions that can extract tgz files in RTEMS. Take a look at the tar01 test for some examples with different sources (memory or file): https://git.rtems.org/rtems/tree/testsuites/libtests/tar01/init.c?id=8d989c56ff0c65beb7ec3390aebef6ea52840fab
Note that this is a test application intended to test the functionality. So some things might try to trigger expected failures. The test tar file is automatically generated by the Makefile, translated into some object file and linked into the application.

There is also the tarfs that can use a tar (not sure about tgz) as a read only file system. It's used in tar02 test.

Regarding libz: Although I haven't tried I would expect that it is possible to compile libz for RTEMS. If you need specifically that library you might want to ask on the RTEMS users mailing list whether someone already did that. There are a lot more RTEMS specific users and developers than on stackoverflow.